# Java replaceAll() method to escape special characters

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am using java `replaceAll()` method to escape new line characters

```
String comment = "ddnfa \n  \r \tdnfadsf ' \r t  ";
comment = comment.replaceAll("(\\n|\\r|\\t)","\\\\$1");
System.out.println(comment);
```

But the above code is still inserting new line.

Is there a way to output the comment exactly the same (i.e. with `\n` and `\r` instead of inserting new line)?

**UPDATE:**

I ended up using:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("\\n","\\\\n")
                 .replaceAll("\\r","\\\\r")
                 .replaceAll("\\t","\\\\t");
```

Comment: Actually i am taking that comment input from user so I don't have control on it.

Comment: try with the regx in my answer. if you are satisfied then rate my answer.

Comment: check the comment in your ans

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to go one-by-one, since the new-line character U+000A has nothing to do with the two-character escape sequence `\n`:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("\n","\\\\n");
comment = comment.replaceAll("\r","\\\\r");
comment = comment.replaceAll("\t","\\\\t");
```

Comment: Why can't we do it using regex?

Comment: You are using regex: a regex that matches only one character.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to do it character by character:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("\n","\\\\n");
comment = comment.replaceAll("\r","\\\\r");
comment = comment.replaceAll("\t","\\\\t");
```

another solution is to escape the String as a Java String using this function:

```
comment = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(comment);
```

This will make the String look exactly like the String in the Java Code, but it will also show other escape sequences (like `\\`, `\"` etc).
But maybe thats exactly what you want

Comment: Why can't we do it using regex?

Comment: because you cant match the `n` of `\n` because there is no `n` in `\n`

Comment: Regular expression literals like `/\n/` are not valid in Java

Comment: i was somehow thinking of javascript :D

Comment: Also you need four backslashes in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

### Hard way: using Matcher

```
String comment = "ddnfa \n  \r \tdnfadsf ' \r t  ";

Map<String,String> sub = new HashMap<String,String>();
sub.put("\n", "\\\\n");
sub.put("\r", "\\\\r");
sub.put("\t", "\\\\t");

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\n|\\r|\\t");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(comment);
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, sub.get(matcher.group()));
}
matcher.appendTail(result);

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

prints

```
ddnfa \n  \r \tdnfadsf ' \r
```

Comment: You forgot to call `matcher.appendTail(result);` after the loop completes.  Also, `matcher.group()` returns the part of the text that was matched, so you don't have to use the `substring` method.

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(stringToBeReplaced);`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
comment.replaceAll("(\n)|(\r)|(\t)", "\n");
```

Comment: new string is that same \n or \r with escape i.e. \\n \\r, my question is how do i change it to that?

Comment: You need \n and \r to be replaced with \n and \r??? can all the \n \r \t be replaced with \n?? will it suite your requirement?

Comment: Actually i am taking that comment input from user so I don't have control on it and user is writing it as commment for his own purpose, so I can't modify it

Comment: Ok then i guess, you can replace all the \n \r with \n??!!

Answer (score 0):

It is a `\` problem, simplify like this :

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("(\n|\r|\t)", "");
```

output :

```
ddnfa    dnfadsf '  t
```

Comment: I want exactly the same output : "ddnfa \n  \r \tdnfadsf ' \r t  ".

Comment: Actually i am taking that comment input from user so I don't have control on it and user is writing it as commment for his own purpose, so I can't modify it

Comment: @AbhishekGoel you can remove it, point your comment and click on the red cross :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#replace` to avoid the required double-escape in the replacement character sequence:

```
comment = comment.replace("\\n","\\n")
                 .replace("\\r","\\r")
                 .replace("\\t","\\t");
```

(`"\n"` is a string containing a single character: a line feed. `"\\n"` is a string containing a two characters: a backslash and the letter n.)